# Why character switching in string is not allowed in Golang?

Tags: string, go, immutability

I understand that Go string is basically an array of byte. What is the explanation why str[0] = str[1] is not allowed? Thanks!

```
str := "hello"
str[0] = str[1]

// expecting eello
```

Comment: [Why are strings immutable in many programming languages?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9544182/995714), [Which types are mutable and immutable in the Google Go Language?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8018081/995714)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I understand that Go string is basically an array of bytes.

Not exactly. A string is made up of

- a pointer to an *array* of bytes, and
- an integer that corresponds to the length of that array.

If you could update individual *runes* of a given string variable, then strings would be mutable, [against the wishes of the Go designers](https://golang.org/ref/spec#String_types):

> Strings are immutable: once created, it is impossible to change the contents of a string.

See also [this post](https://go.dev/blog/strings) on the golang.org blog:

> In Go, a string is in effect a read-only slice of bytes.

Immutability has many advantages—for one thing, it's easy to reason about—but it can be perceived as a nuisance. Of course, overwriting a string variable is legal:

```
str := "hello"
str = "eello"
```

Moreover, you can always convert the string to a data structure that is mutable (i.e. a `[]byte` or a `[]rune`), make the required changes, and then convert the result back to a string.

```
str := "hello"
fmt.Println(str)
bs := []byte(str)
bs[0] = bs[1]
str = string(bs)
fmt.Println(str)
```

Output:

```
hello
eello
```

([Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/MH63yfseWVR))

However, be aware that doing so involves copying, which can hurt performance if the string is long and/or if it's done repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

Go strings are immutable and behave like read-only byte slices,To update the data, use a rune slice instead;

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {

    str := "hello"
    fmt.Println(str)

    buf := []rune(str)
    buf[0] = buf[1]
    s := string(buf)
    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

Output:

```
 hello
 eello
```